# How to change the query so that it checks if the table is not empty

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, exists

I've got a query:

```
INSERT INTO rates (name, value, time) 
SELECT name, value, time
FROM updated_rates
ON CONFLICT (name) DO UPDATE
SET value = excluded.value, time = excluded.time;
TRUNCATE updated_rates;
```

How to change the query so that it does the actions above if updated_rates is not empty

Comment: Not sure what the question is. If `update_rates` is empty, then the SELECT won't return any rows, and thus nothing will be inserted (or updated) in the `rates` table. So there is nothing you need to change in your query to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table is empty, the query will just "do nothing". There is no need in  adding anything to the query for it to work properly

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists`:

```
exists (select * from updated_rates)
```

But if it's empty it will simply not insert anything.